# Line break attribute JEditorPane

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane, word-wrap

Would anyone know how to change the line break attribute for a `JEditorPane`?

I can't locate line breaks in my `JTextPane`s text (it's neither *\n* neither *\r*), and so I can't count the number of lines of this text properly. I would like to change the line break attribute for *\n*.

Comment: What's the content type of the editor??

Comment: the content type is text/plain

Answer (score 3):

This example works for me...

```
public class TestEditorPane {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestEditorPane();
    }

    public TestEditorPane() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new EditorPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class EditorPane extends JPanel {

        private JEditorPane editor;

        public EditorPane() {

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            editor = new JEditorPane();
            editor.setContentType("text/plain");

            JButton button = new JButton("Dump");
            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    String text = editor.getText();
                    String[] parts = text.split(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
//                    String[] parts = text.split("\n\r");
                    for (String part : parts) {
                        if (part.trim().length() > 0) {
                            System.out.println(part);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            add(editor, gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.weightx = 0;
            gbc.weighty = 0;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
            add(button, gbc);
        }
    }
}
```

Under windows, the line break seems to be `/n/r`.  I've used the system property `line.separator` as well, and it seems to work for me.

Answer (score 3):

Use `javax.swing.text.Utilities.getRowStart()/getRowEnd()` to count number of lines.

In fact when text is wrapped no char is inserted. See http://java-sl.com/wrap.html to understand how the wrap works.

Comment: That's what I thought, no char is inserted. I know well the wrap tutorial on java-sl, it's cool to be answered by this same author, Thanks :) The Utilities class is perfect for what I need.